# Change Cursor for Netbeans on Linux

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, gnome, mouse-cursor

I am recently have been successfully installed NetBean 6.8 on Ubuntu Box (10.04).
But the problem is, NetBeans doesn't use the Gnome mouse Cursor by default. instead, It uses some freak mouse cursor that I hate!

So, do you have any idea about how to change the cursor that appears inside netbeans.(I have looked inside tools> options but without any output)

Also I have did:

```
$ grep -iR cursor  *
Binary file var/cache/all-resources.dat matches
Binary file var/cache/all-layers.dat matches
Binary file var/cache/index/s2/javascript/8/1/_0.cfs matches
```

(note, I didn't talked here about how to change the cursor inside some Java program written in NetBeans)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on superuser.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Following workaround works for me.

In my case, I discovered netbeans uses the first cursor theme in "/usr/share/icons" and ignores whatever I set as cursor theme for the desktop.

Let's say the first cursor theme, which is used by netbeans is "/usr/share/icons/firsttheme" and the theme that I want to use is "/usr/share/icons/mytheme".

To solve the problem I simply copy the content of the "/usr/share/icons/mytheme" into "/usr/share/icons/firsttheme".

Do not forget to backup the original theme before copy!

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks. In my case I selected the cursor theme:
ComixCursors-Green-Regular-Slim

What Netbeans was showing, however, was:
ComixCursors-Black-Huge-Slim
(I found this out by comparing the Netbeans cursor to what I saw in Menu > Preferences > Appears > <theme> > Customize > Pointer). 
I backed this up to: 
ComixCursors-Black-Huge-Slim (original).  
Then I copied the contents of ComixCursors-Green-Regular-Slim into ComixCursors-Black-Huge-Slim

Answer (score 3):

Here's the right way to do it:

1. Open a terminal.
2. `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`
3. Pick the choice you want from the list.

This is a Ubuntu bug. The above is the correct workaround.
There is no need to copy files in /usr/share/icons.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Fedora17. Apparently there is no alternative named `x-cursor-theme`.